# Pie Charts NuGet Packages in WPF

Tags: wpf, .net-core, charts, nuget

Does anyone know a good Chart NuGet Package for WPF available in .NET 3.1 or .NET 5.0?

Many NuGet Packages are deprectaed or don't have much documentation.

I already tried:

https://github.com/ScottPlot/ScottPlot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Best solution:**

https://github.com/Live-Charts/Live-Charts

I've tried a few charts and it look fancy as hell.

In the github repo of livecharts there are many examples for wpf:

https://github.com/Live-Charts/Live-Charts/tree/master/Examples/Wpf